# Using AudioInputStream with a ProgressMonitorInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, ioexception, javasound, progressmonitor

**Revised/Summary:**

I'm using a plugin to decode an MP3 audio file. I'd like to provide a `ProgressMonitor` to provide feedback to the user. The logic of constructing an AudioInputStream that decodes the MP3 format AudioFile is as follows:

```
readAudioFile(File pAudioFile) throws UnsupportedAuioFileException, IOException {
    AudioInputStream nativeFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(pAudioFile);
    AudioInputStream desiredFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AUDIO_OUTPUT_FORMAT,nativeFormatStream);
    int bytesRead, bufferLength;
    byte[] rawAudioBuffer[bufferLength=4096];
    bytesRead=desiredFormatStream.read(rawAudioBuffer,0,bufferLength));
   ...
}
```

First attempt was to wrap the audio File with a ProgressMontorInputStream, then get the AudioInputStream from that:

```
readAudioFile(File pAudioFile) throws UnsupportedAuioFileException, IOException {
    ProgressMonitorInputStream monitorStream = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(COMP,"Decoding",new FileInputStream(pAudioFile);
    AudioInputStream nativeFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(monitorStream);
    AudioInputStream desiredFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AUDIO_OUTPUT_FORMAT,nativeFormatStream);
    int bytesRead, bufferLength;
    byte[] rawAudioBuffer[bufferLength=4096];
    bytesRead=desiredFormatStream.read(rawAudioBuffer,0,bufferLength));
   ...
}
```

While it builds, upon execution I get the following when constructing the `AudioInputStream` from the `ProgressMonitorInputStream`:

```
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
```

Comments below confirm that the AudioInputStream requires the InputStream it wraps to support the mark() and reset() methods, which apparently ProgressMonitorInputStream does not.

Another suggestion below is to wrap the ProgressMonitorInputStream with a BufferedInputStream (which does support mark/reset). So then I have:

```
readAudioFile(File pAudioFile) throws UnsupportedAuioFileException, IOException {
    ProgressMonitorInputStream monitorStream = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(COMP,"Decoding",new FileInputStream(pAudioFile);
    AudioInputStream nativeFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(monitorStream));
    AudioInputStream desiredFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AUDIO_OUTPUT_FORMAT,nativeFormatStream);
    int bytesRead, bufferLength;
    byte[] rawAudioBuffer[bufferLength=4096];
    bytesRead=desiredFormatStream.read(rawAudioBuffer,0,bufferLength));
   ...
}
```

Now this builds and executes without error. However, the ProgressMonitor never appears, despite aggressive settings for setMillisToPopup(10) and setMillisToDecideToPopup(10); My theory is that the time to actually read the undecoded audio into memory is still faster than 10mSec. The time is actually spent decoding that raw audio after reading from disk. So the next step is to wrap the undecoded AudioInputStream with the ProgressMonitorInputStream before constructing the decoding AudioInputStream:

```
readAudioFile(File pAudioFile) throws UnsupportedAuioFileException, IOException {
    AudioInputStream nativeFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(pAudioFile);
    AudioInputStream desiredFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AUDIO_OUTPUT_FORMAT,new BufferedInputStream(new ProgressMonitorInputStream(COMP,"Decoding",nativeFormatStream);
    int bytesRead, bufferLength;
    byte[] rawAudioBuffer[bufferLength=4096];
    bytesRead=desiredFormatStream.read(rawAudioBuffer,0,bufferLength));
   ...
}
```

I seem to be kicking the can down the road but not making progress. Is there any workaround for this problem? Is there an alternative way to providing a `ProgressMonitor` for the decoding process? My (unsatisfying) fallback is displaying a busy cursor. Any suggestions for other ways to accomplish the goal - providing visual feedback to the user with at least an estimate of time remaining to complete the decoding?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not quite. The AudioInoutStream has to be at the outside to pass to the relevant APIs. AudioInputStream should wrap BufferedInputStream which should wrap ProgressMonitorInputStream.

Comment: What library are you using to decode the mp3 file?  Since mp3 is a compressed audio type and support tends to be limited, the mark() and reset() functions may not be supported by the library.  I know that's how JLayer is...

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Try `AudioInputStream nativeFormatStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(stream));`

Comment: @MaxFeldkamp You are correct. I am using the JLayer/mp3spi/tritonus decoder plugin.

Comment: @EJP That solved the build problem, but as noted above in the updates to the OP, it did not produce a functioning ProgressMonitor. Any suggestions on how to wrap the decoded AudioInputStream with the ProgressMonitorInputStream?